# Set background color attribute for single cell with Laravel DataTables

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.3

I'm using Yajra Laravel Datatables for my data display with serverside ajax loads, to prevent long loads on large amounts.

Now I want to color single TD in a row depending on the status (and other options)

I found that I can easily add parametes to the whole row, depending on options:

```
->setRowAttr([
    'style' => function($item){
        return $item->disabled ? 'background-color: #ff0000;' : 'background-color: #00ff00;';
    }
])
```

And this produces me:

[image]

But I don't need to color the whole row, only the Bookings TD (in this case) since a different color will be applied for the Active statuses + another one for Room groups, like this:

[image]

How can this be accomplished?

*PS: I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Datatavles 6*

Comment: One day i faced same issue in my case it was fixed luckily using class to row where i want to remove style give a class to booking row as `class="sorting_1"`

Comment: Currently my only idea is to add span with class like `color-me` and data element with the desired color. Then create javascript that fetches all these elements and adds background color to the parent `td` of the each element found.

Comment: @Danis good idea you can try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, solved this myself after reading this documentation
**http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html**:

First I added additional columns before `Datatables make()` call, since the original get overwritten with language outputs, like this:

```
->addColumn('active', function ($item) {
    return $item->disabled ? 0 : 1;
})
->editColumn('disabled', function ($item) {
    $item->disabled ? t('No') : t('Yes');
})
```

Then I added check to JS part right after data call:

```
serverSide: true,
ajax: {
    url: ...,
    type: "get"
},
columns: [
    ...
    {data: 'disabled', name: 'disabled'},
    ...
],
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
    ...
    if ( data['active'] == 1 ) {
        $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('success');
    } else {
        $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('danger');
    }
    ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer

**php:**

```
DataTables::of($query)
->addColumn('stylesheet', function ($record) {
                                return [
                                    [
                                        'col' => 11,
                                        'style' => [
                                            'background' => '#080',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'col' => 12,
                                        'style' => [
                                            'background' => '#c00',
                                            'color' => '#fff',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ];
                            });
```

**javascript:**

```
DataTable({
columns: [...],
createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex, cells) {
                if (data.stylesheet) {
                    $.each(data.stylesheet, function (k, rowStyle) {
                        $(cells[rowStyle.col]).css(rowStyle.style);
                    });
                }
            },
})
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: This project is outdated, but as you can see in the example, it needed specific colors for each cell, not just the whole column in 1 color.

Comment: This is really a nice idea and I do appreciate that you shared it with us! It makes styling of the datatables much easier.